# How to draw images after upgrade from java 7 to java 14

Tags: java, file, graphics, javax.imageio

So i wrote a game under jdk 7 which imported and drew graphics like that:
ImageReader.java:

```
public static BufferedImage button_quit;

public void fetchGraphics() {
   try {
        button_quit = ImageIO.read(new File("rsc/client/gui/button_quit.jpeg"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception thrown in ClientVariables.class while importing overlay graphics.");
    }
}
```

DrawClient.java:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.drawImage(ClientVariables.button_quit, ClientVariables.quitButtonX, ClientVariables.quitButtonY, null);
    repaint();
}
```

The problem - in jdk 7 it worked just fine, but since i upgraded to jdk 14 not a single graphic is imported, it only draws all the lines and stuff that is hardcoded. How do i have to change the code to make it work again, i have no clue (tutorials on how to draw images in java are from years ago therefore also in jdk 7 or 8)

Edit: Its the same code, the same ide not even another folder where stuff is located in. The positions of the graphics are as they should be. What i didn't mention before: The graphics are not loaded. i repeatedly get the stack trace and my error message. Stack Trace:
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
at GUI.ClientVariables.(ClientVariables.java:100)
at MAIN.CodeEntry.main(CodeEntry.java:70)
What i suspect to maybe be the problem is that the code in the newer version doesn't expect the "rsc/" folder to be in the same folder as the "src/" folder but maybe somewhere else.

Comment: Well your old code is wrong. You should NEVER invoke repaint() inside a painting method. I doubt changing JDK will cause Java methods to stop working. The problem is probably the setup of your IDE and the location of your image files. What debugging did you do? Did you verify the image was read? Did you verify the paintComponent() method is executed? Did you verify the x/y values are correct? Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: So, my old code isn't wrong, just out of context. But youre right the post lacks some info, ill edit it. Just a mre is pretty complicated to make since the game has tons of code.

Comment: *since the game has tons of code.* - an [mre] has nothing to do with your application. It is code do demonstrate a problem. Your problem is reading an image. So all you need is a JFrame with a JLabel and then you read the image and create an ImageIcon to add to the JLabel. The whole class will be about 20 lines of code. The point is you need to learn how to read the image. If the image is in the same location and your IDE is set up correctly then it should find the image. Maybe the problem is the classpath?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) for a better way to read the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solved it myself, might be some fuckup by the IDE. Basically, in the old program, the rsc/ folder was located in the same folder as the src/ folder which contains the packages of this application. Now the program searched for the rsc/ folder one folder above. Why? No clue. But it's solved.

Comment: It is not an IDE fuckup.  Basically, your (old) code was written on the assumption that the files it is looking for are in the file system at a particular location *relative to the directory in which you are running the application*.  That's not a portable assumption.  A better idea is to put the resource on the (runtime) resource path and load it from there.  Especially if the image is intended to be *part* of your application; e.g. an image for a button.